# React Native Video not loading local file

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-video

I am adding video recording and preview feature to my react native app.For taking video i used the following code and once recorded i am able to get the output file.Now using the file uri i tried to preview this file to the users using react-native-video component.But it always shows blank screen, but the video is not loaded.

```
import { RNCamera, FaceDetector } from 'react-native-camera';

 <RNCamera
      ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
      }}
      style={{width:width(100),height:height(100)}}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}

      flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
      permissionDialogTitle={"Permission to use camera"}
      permissionDialogMessage={
        "We need your permission to use your camera phone"
      }
    >

 async startRecording() {
        this.setState({ recording: true });
        var self = this;
         this.camera.recordAsync().
        then((data) => {
            self.setState({video:data.uri})
        })
    }
```

Once video variable is avaialbe i tried to load this using below code snippet :-

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';


 {this.state.video !== ''
                ?
                <Video source={{uri: this.state.video}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                
       onError={this.videoError}               
       style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
       :
     <View/>
}
```

The version details are:-

1. "react-native": "0.61.5".
2. "react-native-video": "^5.0.2"
3. "react-native-camera": "^3.15.0"

**This is video file im getting after camera recording finished
"file:///data/user/0/com.dezzexvideo/cache/Camera/94d367ef-c6b8-43c3-844f-7d0d2c6d0ddf.mp4"**

Comment: It could be a permission issue, does your app request storage access permissions?

Answer (score 1):

The file path you mentioned **file:///data/user/0/com.dezzexvideo/cache/Camera/94d367ef-c6b8-43c3-844f-7d0d2c6d0ddf.mp4** - seems to be cache directory file path.

So may be you cannot directly play video from cache directory. you can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

Using `RNFS` first check the file exists on cache path

```
       if(await RNFS.exists(cachefilepath)){
          //then copy the video file to Document Directory using RNFS

         //copyFile(filepath: string, destPath: string): Promise<void>

         RNFS.copyFile(cachefilepath, RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath).then({
         })

       } 
       //Play file from directory path

       <Video source={{uri: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+filename}} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Video source={{uri: "background"}} ... />
```

Your code is trying to load a local file name 'background.[mp4|...]' as media source, while the camera recording is `data.uri`.
Also check whether `data.uri` contains a meaningful filename.

Comment: Thanks but that was my mistake while posting the question

Comment: Which platform are you testing this on? In case it's Android, check `adb logcat` output for ExoPlayer logs. Similarly on iOS, check logs for AVPlayer output.

Comment: no error even i tried to console log onError callback of Video Component but no error